# Am I misunderstanding assert() usage?

Tags: c++, c, assert

I was taking a look at [the `assert()` reference page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cassert/assert/) and I got stuck while I read the given example:

```
/* assert example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main ()
{
  FILE * datafile;
  datafile=fopen ("file.dat","r");
  assert (datafile);

  fclose (datafile);

  return 0;
}
```

> In this example, assert is used to abort the program execution if datafile compares equal to 0, which happens when the previous call to fopen was not successful.

I totally agree that if `fopen()` fails, `assert()` will abort execution. However I'm concerned about the rightness of this example:

In my opinion `assert()` is there to detect cases that **can't normally happen** (like passing a `NULL` pointer to a function whose documentation states it is forbidden).

In this example, failing to open a file is not something that **can't normally happen**. In fact, I can see dozens of reasons why this would fail. The file couldn't exist, the program could run without required privileges, and so on.

I would rather have done something like:

```
/* not longer an assert example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main ()
{
  FILE * datafile;
  datafile=fopen ("file.dat","r");

  if (datafile != NULL)
  {
    // Do something, whatever.
    fclose (datafile);
  } else
  {
    // Report the error somehow.
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Is my understanding of how `assert()` should be used incorrect ?

---

## EDIT AND GOOD NEWS !

It seems the referred site is ruled by rigorous people. Here is the mail I got back from one of the site maintainer:

> Hi Julien, I have to agree, the
>   example code was poorly chosen. It has
>   now been just rewritten to something
>   more appropriate.
>
> Many thanks for
>   pointing this out, and sorry for any
>   inconveniences this may have caused to
>   you.
>
> Best regards,

And the updated example:

```
/* assert example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

void print_number(int* myInt) {
  assert (myInt!=NULL);
  printf ("%d\n",*myInt);
}

int main ()
{
  int a=10;
  int * b = NULL;
  int * c = NULL;

  b=&a;

  print_number (b);
  print_number (c);

  return 0;
}
```

Glad to see that some people do their work well on the Internet ! ;)

Comment: +1 For recognising that this is a bad example.  +2  For then mailing the site contacts.

Comment: Your understanding is spot on. `assert` is for programming errors, not user errors.

Comment: I removed the C++ tag, as there is not a scrap of C++ code in the post.

Comment: To the guy who downvoted the question: why ? @DeadMG: `assert()` can be used in `C++` as well. The tag was just here to widen the audience as people that only do `C++` might also be interested by the answers.

Comment: @ereOn: Then why don't you go ahead and show a C++ use case?

Comment: @DeadMG: Because probably no one, except you, cares. Why is this such a big deal ? The purpose of this question is to understand the usage of `assert()`. Whether this is `C` or `C++` code is totally irrelevant. If it bothers you so much, replace the string litterals with a `std::string`... but then you will probably complain about the `C` tag. Won't you ?

Comment: *In general*, the language tags are for questions *specific* to that language (most languages have `assert` functionality, you'd need hundreds of tags to mark them all), but I'm confused here. From the edit history, it looks like even the first revision of the question had 1. a link to cplusplus.com, and 2. code examples written in C++. I don't get why having the c++ tag is wrong then. Also +1 from here

Comment: While this usage would be evil in real code, utilizing `assert()` to produce short and focused example code has a long tradition. Example code correctly handling all error paths is confusing to look at.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're perfectly right sir. This is a poor usage of `assert`.

Comment: indeed, assert should only be last resort aka world collapse

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I wrote to the contact page to inform them about the problem. I wonder if they will update it.

Answer (score 2):

You are right indeed. As other people have already pointed out, `assert()` will be more than likely compiled out in the release build (I've seen people force the asserts to be left in for the release build).

I just wanted to add a horror story related to this question that I've seen on a code-base:

```
assert(do_something() == NO_ERR);
```

Some people should not be allowed to use a keyboard.

Comment: True. Although it depends on what do_something() does. if do_something() is really do_complex_validation_that_system_state_is_valid() then it *might* be reasonable if it has no side effects

Answer (score 1):

Minor notification: it would be better if you write..

```
FILE * datafile = NULL;
```

Also, assert only works in debug mode... so your method is better.

Comment: Well, this is not my code. And while I usually initialize my local  variables, here `datafile` is assigned right after its declaration, so it doesn't really matter ;)

Good point about debug mode, I didn't even thought of that.

Comment: @Praveen: assert is a macro that does something only when `NDEBUG` isn't defined. So usually in debug mode.